# Word for the relationship between you and the present-day descendants of one of your past-life incarnations

Tags: single-word-requests

Although somewhat (maybe lots) fictitious, is there a word for the relationship between (a) you, and (b) the present-day descendants of one of your past-life incarnations?

**E d i t**
As per @Pam's comment, yes, "I met my ___ for lunch" would do, although the fictional context I had in mind is somewhat more elaborate. Briefly,...

Although correctly addressed, my mail kept getting returned with "undeliverable" stickers. I finally visited a past-life regression hypnotherapist, and discovered that there's no escaping bad karma: In the 1840's I'd been a pony-express rider, killed by belligerent indians while crossing the Great Plains, thus losing all the mail I'd been carrying. And the company held me responsible, thereby denying my past-life wife and children all my death and pension benefits. So I tracked down their (and sort-of-my) present-day descendants to apologize. But they just spat in my face -- no escaping bad karma.

So there you have it all, @Pam, and I suppose it's (predictably) pretty much as goofy as the original question:)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think I know of such a word (so it's an interesting question), but very often single-word-requests on here need a sample sentence. It clarifies if you're looking for a noun/verb/whatever and helps improve the answer quality. Would something like: "I met my ____ for lunch" suffice?

Comment: @Pam Thanks for the comment. Yes, your sentence is fine, and see **Edit** for more elaborate fictional context I had in mind.

Comment: Cool edit. The only place I could think to look would be "The Legend of Korra" or "Avatar: The Last Airbender" - re-incarnation features heavily in those storylines and you might come across some terminology there, but otherwise, I hope someone in the community can answer.

Comment: @Pam Thanks, again. I'll take a look (though there's a bit of a Catch-22 trying to text-search them -- it's the word I'm asking for that I'd want to put in a text search).

Comment: It seems to me that if you believe in a past life, then the relatives from a previous life would be referred to simply as "relatives" and no adjective is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a single word that would be widely understood for this in English. Therefore, you should use a phrase like **past life's relatives** (or **past life's descendants**):

> I know of past lives being verified by current lives meeting past lives relatives, even their birth marks matching etc. — [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pastlives/comments/8hrr9n/tunguska_event_witness/)

> Korra squealed before picking up all five of her past life's descendants into a group hug — [Fanfiction.net](https://fanfiction.net/s/12228952/3/Avatar-Finding-Destiny)

This is the clearest expression I can think of. If you use just "relatives" then there's a good chance for confusion with the people who are related via blood or marriage. And I suspect there are loan words from languages where many people do believe in reincarnation, but they wouldn't be widely understood outside people familiar with that language and culture. (Few people in English speaking areas such as the US believe in reincarnation, which limits the force for such terms to develop or proliferate.)

Answer (score 1):

Going along with your assumption, **past life descendant** would seem to best way to name the concept.

It is admittedly not very imaginative, but it is an aggregation of two commonly used terms with broadly accepted definitions (*past life* and *descendant*).

**past life** though not defined in dictionaries, is a [collocation](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=collocation) in wide use.

> Descendant: One whose descent can be traced to a particular individual or group: *a descendant of Queen Victoria; descendants of a prize-winning horse.* (American Heritage)

I would still consider that aggregation as a neologism; it would actually require an effort at definition, since as soon as one puts one's mind to it, one sees it is not a wholly self-evident concept.

I note that any reasoning would have to conceive two lines carrying through time:

1. Following *up* (back in time) an "incarnations line", composed of an individual's own incarnations over time.
2. Following *down* the "generations line", i.e. the descendants of that ancestor over the successive generations (from father or mother to children).

Hence an individual with identity A, tracking back her or his incarnations line, would hit a past identity A'; at which point one would follow the descendents of that past identity along the genertions line, until one finds the proper individual.

It shows that calling it **past life descendant** describes the thought process.

Let us note, however, that unless one applies some specific rule (e.g. privileging the first-born male son, as in royal families), the number of descendants would tend to increase exponentially with with each generation; hence the whole set of candidates forms a *tree*.

In your case, did you use any specific criteria to identify the *descendants* your were interested in, or to exclude others?

Comment: Thanks, Fralau. Yeah, there's apparently no single word, so **past life descendant**, as per you and Laurel, is probably as good as it gets. (I tried upvoting your answer, but apparently need more points to cast votes.)